# Retrieve object from fetch request Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have a core data entity called "Device" with one attribute called "asset_tag" along with the following code:

```
var endArray: [Device] = []

var request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
            request = Device.fetchRequest()
            request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

endArray = try context.fetch(request) as! [Device]

print (endArray)
```

this prints out the following:

```
[<Device: 0x608000092c00> (entity: Device; id: 0xd000000000140000 <x-coredata://22AC91EB-92B1-4E5B-A5A9-A5924E0ADD3E/Device/p5> ; data: {
    "asset_tag" = 26;
})]
```

All I want it to print out is ['26']

Comment: fetch request returns an array of dictionary you can loop endArray and print values.

Comment: @TusharSharma Yea but it returns an array with all that junk inside. Is there a way to return the array of just the values?

Comment: you can get value from key.

Comment: @TusharSharma well I am looking to save the results as an array of values only so if theres only 1 value or 200 values, I want just the values to be in an array. Do you know the code to get it to do that?

Comment: try below code according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that because `endArray` is a `[Device]`, which means that each entry in it is a `Device`. When you print the array, what you get is the result of calling `debugDescription` on each entry in the array.

If you just want the integer values of the `asset_tag` property in an array, you can get that array using `map`:

```
let tagValues : [Int] = endArray.map { Int($0.asset_tag) }
```

This says that `tagValues` has type `[Int]`, and that you're assigning a value by using `map` to get one value for each entry in `endArray`. That value is found by looking up the value of `asset_tag` on each entry. The result is an array of `Int` corresponding to the `asset_tag` values.

Answer (score 1):

**Try like this-:**

```
func loadData(){
            let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

            do{
              endArray = try context.fetch(request) as! [Device]
                for data in 0..< endArray!.count{
                    if let value = endArray?[data].value(forKey: "Your Key") {
                        print(value)
                    }
                }
            }catch{

            }


        }
```

Comment: I get error cannot subscript a value of type [Device] with an index of type "Device"

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are using a `NSManagedObject` subclass use a specific fetch request to avoid the type cast. And `NSFetchRequest` is reference type. Declare the request as constant (`let`).

A fetch request returns always an array of the entity `[NSManagedObject]`. The *junk* is important. The object can contain many attributes and relationships.

To get an array of a specific attribute use the `map` function

```
var endArray = [Device]()

let request : NSFetchRequest<Device> = Device.fetchRequest()
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

do {
    endArray = try context.fetch(request)
    let tagArray = endArray.map { $0.asset_tag }
    print(tagArray)
} catch { print(error) }
```